# How to replace data in one record with data from another record in a controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

So first I am a absolute beginner, so sorry if my code looks horrible. I am working on a booking platform where users can book seats in a bus and exchange them with each other if they don't need them. Exchanging them is the only way to get rid of a seat booking, they can't simply cancel/delete it.

If a user doesn't need their `Booking` then he/she can create a `Angebot` (offer) on a marketplace/list for that given `Booking`. Other users can request it with a `Anfrage` (request). This `Anfrage` (request) contains alternative data from the requesting user which contains the same columns as `Booking`.
Now I am trying to replace the data in one `Booking` with data from a `Anfrage` (request). This is achieved when the user that created the `Angebot` (offer) and own the `Booking` accepts one of the `Anfrage` (request).

```
def update_booking_durch_anfrage
    @angebot = Angebot.where(id: anfrage_params[:angebot_id]).first 
    @booking = Booking.find_by_id(@angebot)
    @gleiche_anfragen = Anfrage.find_by_id(@angebot)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.update( 
        user_id: @angebot.user_id,
        vorname: @angebot.vorname,
        nachname: @angebot.nachname,
        email: @angebot.email,
        handynummer: @angebot.handynummer
      ) 
        @gleiche_anfragen.destroy
        @angebot.destroy

        format.html { flash[:notice] = 'Die Buchung wurde erfolgreich auf dich übertragen!' and redirect_to action: "index" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here are the `schema.rb` and the relations between the models.

```
create_table "anfrages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "angebot_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "vorname"
    t.string "nachname"
    t.string "handynummer"
    t.string "email"
    t.index ["angebot_id"], name: "index_anfrages_on_angebot_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_anfrages_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "angebots", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "booking_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["booking_id"], name: "index_angebots_on_booking_id"
  end

  create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "bus_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "vorname"
    t.string "nachname"
    t.string "handynummer"
    t.string "email"
    t.index ["bus_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_bus_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_user_id"
  end
```

```
class Angebot < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :user_id, :vorname, :nachname, :email, :handynummer
    belongs_to :booking
    has_many :anfrages
end

class Anfrage < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :angebot
    belongs_to :user
end

class Booking < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :bus
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :angebot
end
```

But right now this method doesn't do what it is supposed to. It simply redirects me to the `edit.html.erb` view from `Anfrages` without doing anything to the data. I think it has to do with the way rails handles updates and the corresponding forms but I have no clue how to change that.

The other thing is that I am no sure if the controller is the right place for this kind of logic and maybe it belongs into the model.

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: `It simply redirects me to the edit.html.erb view from Anfrages without doing anything to the data.` means `@booking.update` fails. You should debug and check `@booking.errors`. The other way to debug is replace `@booking.update` with `@booking.update!` and test it again and comment here what errors you are getting.

Comment: So now it says validation fails. `Validation failed: User must exist, Vorname can't be blank, Nachname can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid`. First I thought it might be because the example data in the db is incomplete, but after using consistent examples and Justins approach it still says Validation failed.

Comment: Clearly the record you get in `@angebot` must have all the mentioned fields empty. Try updating the record with meaningful value and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out what was wrong. First the `link_to` method in my view was sending the wrong params so I set it up correctly. Than `update_booking_durch_anfrage` method wasn't able to fetch this data correctly because of all the relations. I now created this 4 step data fetch approach that seems to work. And the last thing is as you can see that the data which I tried to replace wasn't stored in `Angebot` but in `Anfrage`...

So here's the solution that fetches the right `Booking` and updates it with data from the correct `Anfrage`. It's important that the link in the view uses `PUT`, because you want to update the data. Big thanks also to Justin for his `booking_attributes` method which made it a lot easier.

```
<%= link_to 'Tauschanfrage annehmen', {:controller => "angebots", :action => "update_booking_durch_anfrage", :id => anfrage.id, :angebot_id => anfrage.angebot_id }, :method => :put, data: { confirm: 'Bist du dir sicher, dass du die Tauschanfrage annehmen möchtest?'}, class: 'btn btn-outline-primary' %>
```

As you can see it sends the right parameters which are needed `{:controller => "angebots", :action => "update_booking_durch_anfrage", :id => anfrage.id, :angebot_id => anfrage.angebot_id }`

Next the method in the controller fetches the right data with a lot of `.where` methods.

```
    def update_booking_durch_anfrage  
      @anfrage = Anfrage.where(id: anfrage_params[:id]).first
      @angebot = Angebot.where(id: anfrage_params[:angebot_id]).first
      @booking = Booking.where(id: @angebot.booking_id).first
      @gleiche_anfragen = Anfrage.where(angebot_id: anfrage_params[:angebot_id]).first
        respond_to do |format|
          if @booking.update!(@anfrage.booking_attributes) 
            @gleiche_anfragen.destroy
            @angebot.destroy
            format.html { flash[:notice] = 'Die Buchung wurde erfolgreich übertragen!' and redirect_to action: "index" }
          else
            format.html { flash[:notice] = 'Irgendwas ist schief gegangen...' and redirect_to action: "index" }  
          end
        end
     end



class Anfrage < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :angebot
    belongs_to :user

    validates :vorname, presence: true
    validates :nachname, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true, :format => /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

    def booking_attributes
        %i[user_id vorname nachname email handynummer].map do |a|
          [a, send(a)]
        end.to_h
    end
end

class Booking < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :bus
        belongs_to :user
        has_one :angebot, dependent: :destroy
        validates :vorname, presence: true
        validates :nachname, presence: true
        validates :email, presence: true, :format => /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
end
```

It saves the data after validation in the Model and everything works smoothly. I am sure that's a lot of spaghetti code but it gets the job done...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, your controller's logic goes like

```
if @booking.update(...)
else
 ...
 format.html { render :edit }
end
```

So what is happening is updating the booking isn't working,  returning `false` and redirecting you to the edit view. You can get more insight into exactly why updating that Booking is failing by instead calling `@booking.update!(...)` which will raise an error instead of just returning false if the booking does not update.

Additionally, you may be able to save yourself some headache by defining methods on your models to list those attributes. Something like

```
class Angebot
  def booking_attributes
    %i[user_id vorname nachname email handynummer].map do |a|
      [a, send(a)]
    end.to_h
  end
end

# Controller

@booking.update(@angebot.booking_attributes)
```

Comment: Thanks. That gave me a hint. The method is passing blank data and the validation in the model is failing because the data in the db is older than the validations and this creates inconsistencies.